MudDataGrid Virtualized Default Sort Order
Is it possible to Sort the MudDataGrid when it Loads in Virtualization mode?  Graphically the sort order Arrow is showing but it's not sorting.
Thank you

    <MudDataGrid @ref="refMudDataGrid"
             Items="forecasts"
             Hover="true"
             Elevation="0"
             Filterable="true"
             FilterMode="@DataGridFilterMode.Simple"
             HeaderClass="header-class"
             Virtualize="true"
             Height="500px"
             ItemSize="25"
             OverscanCount="2"
>
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Date" Title="Date" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TemperatureC" Title="Temp. (C)" InitialDirection="SortDirection.Descending" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TemperatureF" Title="Temp. (F)" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Summary" Title="Summary" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>


I added the following Code and now it sorts correctly.  Is this the recommended way of ensuring the sort?
Thank you
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
StateHasChanged();
return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

See https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/9776 for reported issue.

This looks like a bug that needs reporting here https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues.
Your solution is not the fix: it causes a render loop.  Add some console logging into your OnAfterRenderAsync and see what happens:
    private int _counter;

    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine($"Yet another Render {_counter}");
        _counter++;
        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

Yet another Render 1158
Yet another Render 1159
Yet another Render 1160
Yet another Render 1161
Yet another Render 1162
..... endlessly repeating

The get-around-fix is to only call StateHasChanged on the second render.
    private bool _defaultSortingSet;
    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!_defaultSortingSet && refMudDataGrid is not null)
        {
            _defaultSortingSet = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

Impact on Filtering
It doesn't.
Here's my demo page based on all the information you've provided:
@page "/weather"

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Weather forecast</MudText>
<MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mb-8">This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</MudText>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Default" Indeterminate="true" />
}
else
{
    <MudDataGrid @ref="refMudDataGrid"
                 Items="forecasts"
                 Hover="true"
                 Elevation="0"
                 Filterable="true"
                 FilterMode="@DataGridFilterMode.Simple"
                 HeaderClass="header-class"
                 Height="500px"
                 ItemSize="25"
                 OverscanCount="2">
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Date" Title="Date" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TemperatureC" Title="Temp. (C)" InitialDirection="SortDirection.Descending" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TemperatureF" Title="Temp. (F)" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Summary" Title="Summary" />
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private MudDataGrid<WeatherForecast>? refMudDataGrid;
    private bool _defaultSortingSet;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate a loading indicator
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 500).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }

    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!_defaultSortingSet && refMudDataGrid is not null)
        {
            _defaultSortingSet = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

And applying a filter on Summary looks like this.  You can see the sorted and filtered list behind.


Thank you for your response MrC.   How would I update the Record Count when the User Filters?  Your solution takes care of the Sort but would break the recordCount on a user Filter action.
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
UpdateFilteredItemsCount();
return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
private void UpdateFilteredItemsCount()
{
if (refMudDataGrid != null)
{
intFilteredItemsCount = refMudDataGrid.GetFilteredItemsCount();
StateHasChanged();
}
}

MrC in regards to the error being reported.  I am new to C#, Blazor, MudBlazor and GitHub.  It's better if someone more experienced writes the report.

See my updated answer.  Count only comes into play if your using ServerData and providing a delegate to fetch the data.  Your code doesn't show that: your using Items which points to an IEnumerable<T>.  The count is generated internally by the control.

Thank you MrC.  You answer does show the Intial Record count but if you Filter the Grid this code does not update.

    Record Count: @refMudDataGrid.GetFilteredItemsCount().ToString("N0")
